# MySQL - is there a way to implement a CHECK constraint after creating the table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, check-constraints

I created a table and after entering all the data, I found that I had missed a `CHECK` constraint in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

`create table jims_faculty
( fac_id int primary key,
fac_name varchar(15) not null,
fac_address varchar(40),
fac_contact_no int,
fac_qualification varchar(30) default 'post graduate',
fac_designation varchar(30) default 'assistant professor',
Fac_dept varchar(15)  check(fac_dept in ('it' , 'mgmt')) ,
fac_experience int ,
fac_date_of_joining date not null,
fac_aadhar int unique);
fac_aadhar int unique);`

The fac_experience field should not be less than 2 years is the condition that should be in the check constraint.

Should I recreate the table?

Or is there another possibility ?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: i am using the latest version 8.0.19 @Vérace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`MySQL >= 8.16`](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/) when MySQL **finally** implmemented `CHECK` constraints, you can do this following:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
ADD CHECK (check criteria)
```

so in your case, it would be

```
ALTER TABLE jims_faculty
CHECK (fac_experience >= 2)
```

If you want to name the constraint, you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE jims_faculty
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_fac_experience_gt_2 CHECK (fac_experience >= 2);
```

From the [`manual`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) (incredibly) `Prior to MySQL 8.0.16, CREATE TABLE permits only the following limited version of table CHECK constraint syntax, which is parsed and ignored:`

The information in this post was largely gleaned from [`here`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp).

Comment: thank you for answering.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as correct and/or helpful - it may help others with the same problem to find it in future! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Did it.thank you for helping and i am very glad to join you people.

Comment: I edited your question - I hope you approve! :-)